# Dividing Array Into 3 Equal Columns

Tags: php, arrays

I have a dynamic number of items in which I'll need to divide into 3 columns. Let's say I'm given this:

```
array("one", "InfoOne", "LibOne", 
      "two", "InfoTwo", "LibTwo", 
      "three", "InfoThree", "LibThree")
```

I need to generate array like this:

```
array( 
[0] = array("one", "InfoOne", "LibOne"),
[1] = array("two", "InfoTwo", "LibTwo"),
[2] = array("three", "InfoThre", "LibThree")
)
```

How could I do to put in an array, data with 3 equal columns?

Comment: use `array_chunk()`.

Comment: I do `array_chunk($data_array, ceil(count($data_array)/3))`, but I don't get the right result

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: just use 3 as a second parameter, it will sized your main array into 3 column...

Comment: @FrayneKonok `3` as a second parameter will split in chunks of size `3` and not of 3 chunks.

Comment: @u_mulder, yes. I mixed it with this given array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`array_chunk()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_chunk.asp) you can do this-

```
$ori = array("one", "InfoOne", "LibOne", 
      "two", "InfoTwo", "LibTwo", 
      "three", "InfoThree", "LibThree");
$chunked = array_chunk($ori, 3);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($chunked);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
$t1=array("one", "InfoOne", "LibOne", 
      "two", "InfoTwo", "LibTwo", 
      "three", "InfoThree", "LibThree");
      print_R(array_chunk($t1,3));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => one
            [1] => InfoOne
            [2] => LibOne
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => two
            [1] => InfoTwo
            [2] => LibTwo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => three
            [1] => InfoThree
            [2] => LibThree
        )

)
```

Comment: Not sure why you need a `die;` in there

Answer (score 1):

Basically, do this:

```
$array = [
  "one", "InfoOne", "LibOne", 
  "two", "InfoTwo", "LibTwo", 
  "three", "InfoThree", "LibThree"];

print_r($new_array = array_chunk($array,3,true));
```

Should provide a nice new array with 3 and 3 values in multidimensional array.